# Issue with geochart library in vue-chartkick npm package

Tags: vue.js, chartkick

I installed the chartkick package from "https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartkick". Then imported it to the main.ts
but when i include the following html snippet inside my component i get the following error in the console "No charting library found for GeoChart" 
Can anyone please help me out on how to include the GeoChart library. I am not able to find the solution still.

```
          //code
          <geo-chart
            :data="[['United States', 44], ['Germany', 23], ['Brazil', 22]]"
          ></geo-chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the missing library. Just need to include the the geoChart script snippet inside the index.html of the vuejs project

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"> 
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```